# Convergence in probability of a sequence where an element is the maximum element of another sequence

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

In my textbook there is a question as the following:

> *Let $X_{1}, X_{2},...$ be independent random variables that are uniformly distributed over $[-1,1]$. Show that the sequence $Y_{1},Y_{2},...$ converges in probability to some limit, and identify the limit, for each of the following cases.*

The case where I had struggle is the following:

$Y_{n} = max\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\}$

In the solution, the author intuitively picks the number which the sequence converges at, which is $1$. I understand the reasoning behind the intuition, as we add more elements to the sequence of $X$, the maximum value has to approximate $1$. However, I cannot reach this result by using probabilistic properties. Here is my work:

Since we do not know the number which the sequence converges, I denoted it as an arbitrary variable $\alpha$.

$P(|Y_{n} -\alpha|\geq\epsilon) = P(Y_{n} \geq \alpha+\epsilon)+P(Y_{n} \leq \alpha - \epsilon) $

$= P(max\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\} \geq \alpha + \epsilon) + P(max\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\} \leq \alpha - \epsilon)$

$= 1 - P(max\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\} < \alpha + \epsilon) + P(max\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\} \leq \alpha - \epsilon)$

$= 1 - P(X_{1} < \alpha + \epsilon, ...,X_{n} < \alpha + \epsilon) + P(X_{1} \leq \alpha - \epsilon, ...,X_{n} \leq \alpha - \epsilon) $

$= 1 - P(X_{1} < \alpha + \epsilon)\cdots P(X_{n} < \alpha + \epsilon) + P(X_{1} \leq \alpha - \epsilon)\cdots P(X_{n} \leq \alpha - \epsilon) $

Since $X_{i}$ is uniformly distributed over $[-1,1]$, CDF is known.

$= 1 - (\frac{\alpha + \epsilon + 1}{2})^{n} + (\frac{\alpha - \epsilon + 1}{2})^{n}$

So, if the sequence converges at $\alpha$, then this expression must go to $0$ as $n$ approaches to $\infty$. However, even if I pick $\alpha$ as $1$ intuitively, I cannot prove that this limit approaches to $0$. Is my limit knowledge not enough, or am I missing some steps in the derivation?

Answer (score 1):

$(Y_n)$ is an increasing bounded sequence so $Y =\lim Y_n$ exist a.s. (hence also in probability). The limit is $1$: If $-1 \leq x <1$ then $P(Y \leq x)=P(X_n \leq x \, \forall n)\leq (\frac {x+1} 2)^{n}$ for all $n$ and $(\frac {x+1} 2)^{n} \to 0$ (because $0 \leq \frac {x+1} 2 <1$). SO $P(Y \leq x)=0$ for all $x <1$. Of course $P(Y \leq 1)=1$ so $Y=1$ a.s.